# Adapting PyQt5 Stopwatch Program to allow GPIO button presses

Tags: pyqt, gpio

I have written this code that has 11 timers, Each timer has 3 buttons Start, Stop, Reset. There is a square box that changes colour depending on the state of the timer, green for running, orange for running over 15 seconds, red for stopped, and yellow for idle. Also each time a timer is reset a counter appears showing the reset amount. I have made it so once the reset button is pressed, you cant press again to add more to the counter.

What i want, is to replace the three buttons with GPIO buttons with these pins:

`start_pins = {14,15,18,23,24,25,8,7,12,10,11}` (Always HIGH, when pressed they are LOW)

`reset_pins = {4,17,27,22,10,9,11,5,6,13,19}` (Always LOW, when pressed they are HIGH)

`stop_pin = 26` (This should stop all timers, it is an emergency stop button that latches and stays pressed)

For example, if i was to press start button on pin 15, Station 2's timer should begin counting. and when reset button on pin 17 is pressed, Station 2's timer should reset, and you should not be able to press it again until timer is started.

Can anyone help me understand where to implement this, i dont expect anyone to complete the task for me obviously, i just need some help.

```python
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTime, QTimer, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPalette, QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout
 
 
class StopWatch(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.name = name
        self.time = QTime(0, 0, 0)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update)
        self.is_running = False
        self.counter = 0
 
        self.label = QLabel(name)
        self.label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16, QFont.Bold))
        self.time_label = QLabel(self.time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        self.time_label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 16))
        self.start_button = QPushButton("Start")
        self.stop_button = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.reset_button = QPushButton("Reset")
 
        self.start_button.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop)
        self.reset_button.clicked.connect(self.reset)
        self.reset_button.setEnabled(False)
 
        hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        hlayout.addWidget(self.start_button)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.stop_button)
        hlayout.addWidget(self.reset_button)
 
        vlayout = QVBoxLayout()
        vlayout.addWidget(self.label)
 
        # Adding a yellow square box to the left of the timer
        self.yellow_box = QWidget(self)
        self.yellow_box.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.yellow))
        self.yellow_box.setMinimumWidth(20)
        self.yellow_box.setMinimumHeight(20)
        self.yellow_box.setMaximumWidth(60)
 
        timer_hlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        timer_hlayout.addWidget(self.yellow_box)
        timer_hlayout.addWidget(self.time_label)
 
        vlayout.addLayout(timer_hlayout)
        vlayout.addLayout(hlayout)
 
        self.setLayout(vlayout)
 
    def set_box_color(self, color):
        palette = self.yellow_box.palette()
        palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, color)
        self.yellow_box.setPalette(palette)
 
    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.timer.start(1000)
            self.is_running = True
            self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.green))
            self.reset_button.setEnabled(True)
 
    def stop(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.is_running = False
            if self.time.second() > 15:
                self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.red))
            else:
                self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.red))
            if self.time == QTime(0, 0, 0):
                self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.red))
        else:
            self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.red))
 
    def reset(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.is_running = False
        self.time = QTime(0, 0, 0)
        self.time_label.setText(self.time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        self.set_box_color(QColor(Qt.yellow))
        self.counter += 1
        self.label.setText(f"{self.name} - Count: {self.counter}")
        self.reset_button.setEnabled(False)
 
    def update(self):
        self.time = self.time.addSecs(1)
        self.time_label.setText(self.time.toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        if self.time.second() > 15:
            self.set_box_color(QColor(255,165,0))
 
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
 
        self.timers = []
 
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
 
        grid_layout = QGridLayout(central_widget)
        grid_layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        grid_layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
 
        # Create multiple instances of StopWatch and add them to the grid layout
        for i in range(6):
            timer = StopWatch(f"Station  {len(self.timers) + 1}", self)
            self.timers.append(timer)
            grid_layout.addWidget(timer, i, 0)
 
        for i in range(5):
            timer = StopWatch(f"Station {len(self.timers) + 1}", self)
            self.timers.append(timer)
            grid_layout.addWidget(timer, i, 1)
 
 
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: What is it that you want to know? How to get GPIO signals into a pyqt program in general, or something specific to this example?

Comment: Specific to this example really would help

Comment: So you already know how to get the GPIO signals into the program, but you don't know how to connect them to the stopwatches. Can you explain in more detail what you would like to know. It seems pretty straightforward to connect the signals to the 'start', 'stop', and 'reset' methods of the stopwatches. It would also be helpful if you could show what the GPIO code looks like. I have no experience with that but I can probably help you beyond that.

Comment: Kind of, The program runs has 11 stopwatches. And i want the first pin in the start array to be able to start the first timer. I just dont know where i place it, i have tried placing it in the INIT,  and main, i can see that it starts all timers, but the timers dont increment. I dont really know how else to describe it.  I tend to use `if GPIO.input(start_pin) == GPIO.LOW ` and then add the functions.

Comment: Can you give a link to the gpio lib you're using

Comment: Not sure how to use links in stackoverflow. But i use the RPi.GPIO library.

Comment: After a quick look, is this my advise: Set up GPIO edge detection in QThread and use custom signals to send the state changes to the main GUI. There you connect those signals to a method that executes the appropriate functions on the stopwatches.
(and if you don't know how to do formatting in the comments, press the help button at the bottom right)

Comment: Thanks! Any chance, you could show me a demo of how this would work in my code, would be a tremendous help to me

Comment: If you need further help with the GPIO side of things things, you better make a separate question out of that. That is not Qt related and will draw a bigger crowd than here. There are plenty of examples on SO how to communicate outside info from a QThread to the GUI, just search for it and try to get it working. If you still can't manage, edit the question to show your (non working) code and ask for help on specific problems. We don't do tutorials here.

Comment: A little bonus tip: you don't need two loops to populate the grid. `for i in range(12): row, column = divmod(i, 2)`